# Cannot cast from Field to EntityManager inside EJB with reflection

Tags: java, casting

I want to get dynamically `EntityManager` in EJB with reflection. I have this code :

```
    @Stateful
    @Local(ContextLocal.class)
    public class ContextBean implements ContextLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="00")
    private EntityManager emBeta;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="01")
    private EntityManager emPretoria;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContextBean.class);

    public ContextBean() {}

    @Override
    public void createAccount(String pseudo, char[] password, String email, TemperamentEnum temperament, Universe universe, int galaxie, int solarSystem, int position) throws PSQLException {

        // Récupération de l'EntityManager adequat en fonction de l'univers choisi
        EntityManager em = getEmFromUniverse(universe);

    }

    /**
     * retourne un EntityManager en fonction d'un univers donné
     * 
     * @param universe
     * 
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    private EntityManager getEmFromUniverse(Universe universe){

        EntityManager em = null;

        try {

            Field[] fields = Class.forName(getClass().getPackage() + "ContextBean").getDeclaredFields();

            for(Field field : fields){
                if(!field.getType().equals(EntityManager.class))
                    continue;
                if(field.getName().replaceFirst("^em", "").equalsIgnoreCase(universe.getName()))
                    return (EntityManager)field; // ERROR HERE
            }

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
        }

        return em;      
    }

}
```

I can not cast `Field` to `EntityManager` :

> Cannot cast from Field to EntityManager

How can I cast `Field` to `EntityManager` object please ?

**EDIT :**

I can have the name of my `universe` object by doing `universe.getName()` and I will get `beta` or `pretoria`.

I know I could use getter to retrieve the right EM :

```
if(universe.getName().equals("beta"))
   return emBeta;
else
   ...
```

but the number of my EMs inside my EJB will probably increase. So with reflection, the code is slower (but it will be only used once per user at register) but I won't have to change it when I will add new EM. That's why I do not use getters.

Any drawback to use reflection in my case ?

**EDIT2 :**

Can transaction integrity of my retrieved EM be lost ?

Answer (score 1):

You should supply object that contains field you need to get:

```
boolean isAccessible = field.isAccessible();
try {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(this); // <-- pass object instance here
} finally {
    field.setAccessible(isAccessible);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just used `return (EntityManager)(field.get(this));` because all my EMs are in my EJB in which I use this code and it works great.

Comment: @hoaz - how is this answer different from the one I posted?

Comment: They are the same, and were posted at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a Field to an EntityManager because they are not in the same class hierarchy. What you ***really*** want to do is get the *value* of the Field as an `EntityManager`:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
final EntityManager manager = (EntityManager) field.get(universe);
```

The code above shows you *how* to do this, but I would strongly recommend against this approach. Why do you need to get the Entity Manager via reflection when you can create a getter on your Context object and return it that way? The reason I would advise against using reflection is because your entity bean is going to be proxied by your application container, and using reflection may not produce the results you expect.

Comment: @hoaz - yes, I noticed that. He is retrieving one of the entity managers on his Context object based off a name field on the `Universe`. Very weird. But, same logic can be accomplished by providing getters on Context and doing a simple `if(name.equals(whatever)) return somestuff;`.